# Создание экземпляра класса Graphics в java

Tags: java, graphics, awt

Изучаю рисование в java. Везде в примерах показывают рисование на основной панели окна.А мне нужно рисовать на созданной мной подпанели. Как можно создать экземпляр класса Graphics и привязать его к нужной панели?

```
    JPanel drawPan = new JPanel();
    Graphics canvas = drawPan.getGraphics();
```

когда пытаюсь рисовать что то через canvas вылетает ошибка nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать BufferedImage - таким образом можно использовать Grafics.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
Grafics grafics = bufferedImage.getGrafics();
JPanel drawPan = new JPanel();
drawPain.paint(grafics);
```

Тут есть примеры:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html